# How does a Decision Tree model choose thresholds in scikit-learn?

Tags: machine-learning, random-forest, scikit-learn, cart

I was reading a book on ML and it says

> Actually, since the training algorithm used by Scikit-Learn is stochastic you may get very different models even on the same training data (unless you set the random_state hyperparameter)

I wonder if such randomness is due to the way thresholds are chosen in scikit-learn. So the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/tree.html#mathematical-formulation) explains how scikit-learn splits a node based on a single feature and a weighted impurity measure. And for now, let's consider each feature before making a split (i.e., set `max_features=None`) and make sure there is no randomness coming from our choice of features.

---

My understanding is if we use the same training set, and if we select a finite number of thresholds based on a non-random rule, for example, use midpoints (i.e., $(x_{(i)}^j + x_{(i+1)}^j) / 2$, $x_{(i)}^j$ is the $i$-th smallest value ranked by $j$-th component for each training vector $\mathbf{x}$) as thresholds. Then it's very likely there's only one global solution $(j, t_m)$ for the best split. The randomness only kicks in when there're more than one minima we can use for splitting.

Also, besides `random_state` being used for selecting features (when `max_features!=None`) to be considered when looking for the best split, where else is it used?

Answer (score 2):

In random forests, stochasticity is mainly caused by the following two factors:

- For each tree, only a subset of features is selected (*randomly*), and the decision tree is trained using only those features
- For each tree, a *bootstrap* sample of the training data set is used, i.e. dataset sampled with *replacement*. In sklearn, this can be controlled via `bootstrap` parameter.

In a Decision Tree, we have none of them. There may also be other sources of randomness due to implementation differences. For example, `DecisionTree` in `sklearn` uses a `splitter` argument which is `best` by default, however it can be set to `random`. `RandomForest` uses this class with default attributes, i.e. `splitter=best`, where the threshold to choose is the *[arithmetic average](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/7813f7efb5b2012412888b69e73d76f2df2b50b6/sklearn/tree/_splitter.pyx#L467)* of boundary values. There seems to be no *random-rule* here.

For [Decision Tree](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.html), (and therefore Random Forest), the following explanation is given in the documentation (which you've also found in the RF's explanation page):

> The features are always randomly permuted at each split. Therefore,
>   the best found split may vary, even with the same training data and
>   max_features=n_features, if the improvement of the criterion is
>   identical for several splits enumerated during the search of the best
>   split. To obtain a deterministic behaviour during fitting,
>   random_state has to be fixed.

This means, if `max_features=None`, `splitter = 'best'`, it's less likely to be random, yes; but, since the features are randomly shuffled at each node, if two of them gives the same gain, we end up with different trees at different runs. Note that, this property is *implementation specific*.

Comment: My original question is actually about the decision tree (not the random forest). So if I set `max_features=None`, `splitter=best` for a decision tree in `sklearn`, it's less likely to be random (unless multiple best splits exist), right?

Comment: I dug in the document a bit on random forest and found this `The features are always randomly permuted at each split. Therefore, the best found split may vary, even with the same training data, max_features=n_features and bootstrap=False, if the improvement of the criterion is identical for several splits enumerated during the search of the best split. To obtain a deterministic behaviour during fitting, random_state has to be fixed.`

Comment: I feel like it basically means if we set `max_features=n_features`, `bootstrap=False`, `random_state=constant`, then a random forest is not longer random. But why there is no `splitter` argument for `RandomForestClassifier`, does it always use  `splitter=best` for the trees it uses?

Comment: I've edited my answer to address your first and second comments. The `random-forest` tag in the question affected my interpretation of the question statement. For the randomness of an algorithm, it'll be quite subjective, but here it is: Disabling feature and sample selection in RFs would have made it deterministic; however, the shuffling in scikit-learn, even if it is predictable via `random_state` parameter, is still a stochastic procedure. We just feed the random numbers that we know. This doesn't make it deterministic since we still rely on random nums;it makes the procedure reproducible.

Comment: And, I think it's just an implementation decision to put the `splitter` argument in RF class; because using random DTs is specific to the library.